# I want to type a tilde in bash, but pressing F10 gives me '1~' instead of just '~'

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, conemu

Previously I was able to output the tilde symbol in my bash terminal by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>. Now when I press <kbd>F10</kbd> I get two characters: `1~`. Same goes for <kbd>F9</kbd>/<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>. Weirdly, the other function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> give me a tilde, but I want <kbd>F10</kbd> to be my tilde key.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: you probably need to create a new keyboard layout for your purpose. On Windows it can be done with [MSKLC](https://superuser.com/q/695293/241386). [Italian keyboard: entering the tilde (~) and backtick (`) characters without changing keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/667622/241386)

Comment: you can press the ~ button on the key board

Comment: That doesn’t answer my original question, which was how you get F10 (raw) to output a tilde.

Answer (score 8):

None of those keys are tilde keys. They all generate a multiple character sequence, such as `ESC [24~` for the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, or `ESC [15~` for the <kbd>F5</kbd> key (although F1–F4 are *slightly* different), or even `ESC [5~` for the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> key.

The only reason you *get* a tilde is because Bash's key-sequence parser consumes the common part that it knows (`ESC [2`) and stops *as soon as it knows* that the full sequence will be unknown. Everything that follows (not neccessarily a tilde!) gets interpreted separately.

Note that this behavior may differ between terminal-based programs: Bash (readline) has its own code for interpreting special keys, Vim has its own, Irssi has its own again. Some programs might fully recognize your keypress as F10 (and therefore ignore it).

---

To make <kbd>F10</kbd> an actual tilde key *globally* (OS-wide), search for "key remapper" tools (perhaps AutoHotkey).

---

To make <kbd>F10</kbd> a tilde key in all *terminal-based* programs, search through the terminal's settings. (The 'terminal' in this case refers to ConEmu.)

The terminal *might* have its own functionality for redefining single keys, or perhaps creating "macros". (The ConEmu [documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html) suggests defining a macro with the `print(…)` action.)

---

To make <kbd>F10</kbd> a tilde key in Bash (but only Bash):

1. Make sure that your terminal emulator (ConEmu) hasn't bound F10 to some function of its own. (Plain F10 is usually not bound to anything – however, Shift+F10 is the standard key for opening the "right-click" menu.)
2. In bash, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (literal insert) and *then* <kbd>F10</kbd>. You will see a sequence like `^[[21~`.

   (The initial `^[` represents ESC, while the rest are just literal symbols.)

   If, at this point, the key doesn't insert any sequence *at all*, that means it has been taken over by the terminal itself or another program – go back to step 1.
3. Open (or create) the `~/.inputrc` file in a text editor.
4. Add this line, taking the sequence from step #2 and replacing `^[` with `\e`:

   ```
   "\e[21~": "~"
   ```

   This tells inputrc to insert a `~` upon receiving `ESC [21~`.
5. Reopen the Bash shell (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reload inputrc).

Comment: `~/.inputrc` is for `readline(3)` library. Programs other than Bash may use it as well and some do. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

What keyboard layout you are using?

There is a dedicated tilde <kbd>~</kbd> key just above <kbd>Tab</kbd> on standard US keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Many European keyboards are notorious for [lacking the tilde (~) and backtick (`) keys](https://superuser.com/q/667622/241386)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this my removing ~.inputrc which had nothing useful in it anyway.

Comment: Can you explain *why* removing this fixed the problem? In particular, consider the next person with this problem...what information do they need to consider to determine whether removing it will fix the problem for them?